# how to use json as input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

```
{  
    "entry":  
       {  
          "city_id": "1234",  
          "city_name": "California"  
       }  
    }
```

Consider this is the json i receive from api. I want the values of the city_id and city_name assigned to a variable.
How to do in ruby?

Comment: you should map the json with some ActiveResource object

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a JSON parsing library. Here's one with examples: http://flori.github.com/json/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `multi_json` gem in my app. I decode my requests like so:

```
data = MultiJson.load(params[:json])
puts data["entry"]["city_name"] # California
```